# How to compare two typedesc in a template for equality

Tags: nim-lang

I'd like to be able to compare two typedesc in a template to see if they're referencing the same type (or at least have the same type name) but am not sure how. The `==` operator doesn't allow this.

```
type
  Foo = object
  Bar = object

template test(a, b: expr): bool =
  a == b

echo test(Foo, Foo)
echo test(Foo, Bar)
```

It gives me this:

```
 Error: type mismatch: got (typedesc[Foo], typedesc[Foo])
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` operator helps: http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#generics-is-operator

```
type
  Foo = object
  Bar = object

template test(a, b: expr): bool =
  #a is b # also true if a is subtype of b
  a is b and b is a # only true if actually equal types

echo test(Foo, Foo)
echo test(Foo, Bar)
```